# Что такое buckets или бакет?

Tags: java, терминология, hashmap

Смотрю картинку про хэш‑таблицу и вижу такое слово: buckets. Посоветуйте что это такое и для чего?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: стоит добавить в вопрос картинку, которую ты смотришь

Comment: @Grundy сейчас добавлю

Comment: @StrangerintheQ То есть там в лежат имена и фамилии в алфавитном порядке? Ну раз упорядоченный?

Comment: в hashmap - в порядке добавления, насколько я помню

Comment: Слово "buckets" переводится не как "корзины", оно переводится "вёдра". Со школы помним известную в мире игру баскетбол, а не "бакетбол"...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Бакетом (*англ. bucket — ведро*) называют набор элементов хеш‑таблицы с совпадающими/близкими значением хеш‑функции.

Хеш‑функция может принимать большой диапазон значений. Из-за технических ограничений (например, при необходимости экономии памяти) внутренний массив хеш‑таблицы может содержать меньшее количество элементов. Тогда элементы с близкими значениями хеша попадут в одну ячейку.

Ситуацию когда у двух элементов, добавленных в хеш‑таблицу совпадают значение хеша называют коллизией. При этом оба элемента попадают в одну ячейку (корзину/ведро) хеш‑таблицы. Большое число коллизий приводит к замедлению работы хеш‑таблицы.

См. [Хеш‑таблица/Разрешение коллизий в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B9)

### Картинка

Картинка иллюстрирует конкретный алгоритм разрешения коллизий — [открытую адресацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Все элементы хеш-таблицы распределяются по 255 ячейкам (число дано для примера, количество ячеек может быть произвольным). У «John Smith» и «Sandra Dee» хеш совпадает. Оба значения размещаются рядом в хеш‑таблице. При использовании этого алгоритма разрешения коллизий это влияет на следующий элемент «Ted Baker», который перемещается в следующую по порядку корзину несмотря на то что имеет уникальный хеш.

Надо сказать, что класс `HashMap` в Java на данный момент использует другой тип разрешения коллизий, в котором каждый бакет представляет из себя дерево поиска, хотя это деталь реализации, не указанная в JavaDoc. Количество бакетов в `HashMap` можно задать с помощью capacity и растет по мере необходимости.

Comment: А почему здесь до 255 именно не подскажите?)

Comment: это пример, могло быть другое число

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, точно пример? совпадает, почему-то с размером байта

Comment: @Dred то есть вы полагаете что в hashmap не влезет 257 элементов? =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ,не, конечно влезет, может быть только, что в последней ячейке будет указан адрес на новый адрес в памяти, где будет храниться новая информация, что-то типо Linked

Comment: @MikeMclaren Прокоментировал картинку